# How to make this kind of htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
/tv-shows/survivor/

<a href="/tv-shows/survivor/"></a>

/tv-shows/survivor/season-37

<a href="/tv-shows/survivor/season-37"></a>

/tv-shows/survivor/season-37/episode-8

<a href="/tv-shows/survivor/season-37/episode-8"></a>
```

This how I want to structure the website navigation.
I have different nested folders where php files are stored.
In (tv-shows) folder i store series names files. Like survivor.php and (season) folders .
In (season) folder i store seasons files like season-37.php and (Episodes) folders.
In (Episodes) folder i store all episode names like episode-8.php.

I want to know how to structure this kind of .htaccess to achieve this kind on structure.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just normal RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ seriesname.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all you files in sub-directories like so:

```
tv-shows/    
   index.php (for /tv-shows)
   survivor/
       index.php (for /tv-shows/survivor)
       season 1/ 
          index.php (for /tv-shows/survivor/season-1)
          episode-1.php (for /tv-shows/survivor/season-1/episode-1)
          episode-2.php
          ...
       season 2/
          index.php
          episode-1.php
          episode-2.php
          ...
```

To remove the .php extension you can add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However I recommend just moving to a proper framework that has a routing feature as your asking for a mantainence nightmare.

Have a look at: [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), or a dedicated PHP routing library [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/). A framework would be better however.